# Is there a performance difference when adding Fields toboth TxxxQuery and TClientDataSet

Tags: delphi

When I use a TClientDataSet which is connected to a TxxxQuery component, I can add TFields to both components at design time. I recognized, when I don't specify the TFields in the TxxxQuery component, they are retrieved when the query is executed at runtime.

My questions is: Is there a performance difference when I add the TFields at design time to the TxxxQuery component?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the fields at design time you get the strongly typed `QueryName_FieldName` fields you can use directly from code, skipping the name-based `QueryName["FieldName"]` lookup required if you don't have them.

From a performance stand-point the difference is most likely insignificant; From a language perspective having the fields added at design time provides better type safety, but only if you access the fields from code, and only if you use the `QueryName_FieldName.Value` syntax, not the named-based `QueryName["FieldName"]` syntax. If you use data-bound controls there's no difference.

I personally only add fields to `TClientDataSet` at design time when I need to use the client dataset without binding it to an other data source (ie: use it as a temporary table for reporting).

Comment: Does it mean, that the metadata from the database is always read by the TxxxQuery compoenent? Or is that call so fast, that it doesn't affect the performance?

Comment: @max, it depends of what you mean by reading metadata... anytime you prepare or execute an unprepared query, the query will get a _description_ of the result set and will match your persisted fields or create new ones based on that information, that way the application knows if all the persisted fields are present and if the data types are the same as declared at design time.